# Regex to test md5sum file format

Tags: java, regex

I need test correct format of md5sum file.
The format is 32 hexadecimal characters, two spaces and after this, any string of characters.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5sum

```
@Test
public void testMD5() {
    String pattern = "^[0-9abcdef]{32} {2}[\\w]*";
    Assert.assertTrue( Pattern.compile( pattern ).matcher("18742594636e452218b9b3bca10c07f2  dashboard.xml").matches() );
    Assert.assertFalse( Pattern.compile( pattern ).matcher("18742594636e452218b9b3bca10c07f2 dashboard.xml").matches() );
}
```

Comment: You're missing `d` in your pattern!

Comment: "32 hexadecimal characters, two spaces and after this, any string of characters" could easily be translated into a regex, if you put *some* effort into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.*` instead of `[\\w]*`

```
String pattern = "^[0-9a-f]{32}[ ]{2}.*$";
                                     ^---two spaces and after this, any string of characters
```

Comment: I think pattern should be `^[0-9a-f]{32}[ ]{2}.+$` because `^[0-9a-f]{32}[ ]{2}.*$` matches strings with empty filename.